# Class not recognized even though header is included

Tags: c++

So I've defined polygon like so (there are other methods, but here's the minimally compileable version).

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gvector3.h"
#include "gmatrix3.h"
#include <nearlyEquals.h>
#include <vector>

class Polygon {

private:

    std::vector <gVector3> vertices;
    std::vector <gVector3> color;

public:

Polygon();

};
```

Now I have a header file where I want to declare the method, draw(Polygon &p). It's shown below. Again, there are other methods, but here's the minimal version.

```
 #include "polygon.h"
 #include "glew.h"
 #include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>

 class MyGLWidget : public QGLWidget {
  protected:
     void initializeGL(void);
     void paintGL(void);
     void resizeGL(int, int);
     void drawPolygon(Polygon &p);
  };
```

The strange thing is that "void drawPolygon(Polygon &p) returns the error, Polygon not a type. I've attached a screenshot of the error here. Can someone help me explain why this error is occurring? I'm not getting any errors of this kind in any of my other methods.

[image]

Comment: Do a pre-process (`gcc -E`) and you have the file with all header files' content in it, then you can see what's wrong.

Comment: Ok I don't know how to do that.. can I do this manually?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explicitly state the names of the two files you've shown.

Comment: The only thing I can see that looks funny is the missing `;` from the end of the `MyGLWidget` class - the line that coincidently, immediately follows the error.

Comment: @enhzflep sorry, that's a typo! the semi colon is there

Comment: @Agentlien the two names are "polygon.h" and "myglwidget.h"

Comment: The error is thrown in ui_opengldemo.h, not in myglwidget.h, are you compiling the right project?

Comment: Add `#error Polygon.h included` temporarily immediately above your polygon class. save files and rebuild the world. If you get the same error message and **don't** break on the `#error` temporarily added, you're somehow including a different header file. Alternatively, you may be header-guarding your include file with  a macro that is actually already defined by a prior include. If you have header guards, update your posted code to show them.

Comment: Is there an include guard in your header file? Something like '#pragma once' or #ifndef POLYGON_H\n #define POLYGON_H\n <your-header-here> #endif ?If you do not have it, it can be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @urzeit I only have one project open at the moment...

Comment: @AmazingVal then do as i said. Immediately *above* your `class Polygon` line in your header, put a single line, `#error Polygon.h included`. Then *save all files* and recompile. if that error doesn't trip, you're either including the wrong file or your using a header guard fencepost macro defined somewhere else that is precluding your source from ever being reached.

Comment: @WhozCraig ok, do i put this above the #ifndef Polygon_H line?

Comment: Ok that error "tripped"

Comment: @WhozCraig The error shows up in my compiler output..

Comment: Then your file is being included by *someone*, but is it the same source file exhibiting the error you're showing (`./ui_opengldemo.h` according to your error log) ? I ask because the file you're "building" is actually `../OpenGLDemo_2/opengldemo.cpp`, and i wonder whether there is a similar `polygon.h` header in *that* folder (and please, *please*, do as asked before and label each source list above with the *exact* file names and preferably their paths relative to the project folder).

Comment: Make the whole example smaller. Then make it even smaller until you have only one file including the other, everything else inline. After that is done make it yet even smaller by directly pasting the declaration of Polygon into the other file, so you only have one file. Along the way you will find the answer OR the universe will implode.

Comment: This is neither minimal nor compilable. I know it may seem silly that everyone's so picky about the code, but we're not mind readers. If you want our help, you're going to have to put a little more effort in so that we've actually got a reasonable shot at identifying the problem.